# How to tell LaTeX what I write should stay as it is, and not as a mathematical expression

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to write my thesis on LaTeX and I don't have much experience with it. I try to put an information about some arrays I used as a table one like looks like this: column names:

```
FileName, Strain, Replicate
```

for this I use this code:

```
\begin{tabular}

US45102998_251897210500_S01_GE1_107_Sep09_1_3.txt & RAL765 & 1 \

\end{tabular}
```

what latex thinks it is: `US45102998251897210573S01GE1107Sep0911.txt` It creates this line where the numbers after underscore are subscripts of the former text. I used `\textdollar{}` and it didn't work for me . I used `\verb{}`, and it worked (it didn't turn the text into a mathematical expression), but now I see `}` sign right after the text and it doesn't break the line.

the full code is:

```
\begin{center}

\tablehead{Array Information}

\toprule

\tableheadline {File Name} & \tableheadline{Strain} & \tableheadline{Replicate} \ \midrule

\hline}

\tabletail{\multicolumn{4}{r} {Continued on next page...} \}

\tablecaption{Array information}

\xentrystretch{0}

\begin{tabular}{llll{5 cm}}

\label{xtab: arrayinformation}

And at the end it is:

\hline

\end{xtabular}

\end{center}
```

Any suggestions? Note: I'm not so familiar with LaTeX lingo.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), some better solution can be devised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably are looking for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xtab,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\tablehead{
  \toprule
  File Name & Strain & Replicate \\
  \midrule
}

\tabletail{\multicolumn{3}{r} {Continued on next page...}\\}

\tablecaption{Array information}

\xentrystretch{0}

\begin{xtabular}{>{\catcode`_=12 }lll}
US45102998_251897210500_S01_GE1_107_Sep09_1_3.txt & RAL765 & 1
\end{xtabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Copied from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18881520/1968):

It’s rather unfortunate that LaTeX by default thinks that `_` only belongs in math mode. If you want to use it in text mode, you need to use `\_` instead.

The [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-underscore) gives more details about the usage of underscores in LaTeX.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `\verb{}`! Instead, choose a delimiter that does not appear in the verbatim text, such as `+`, `|`, `:` but not `*`. Example:

```
\verb|US45102998_251897210500_S01_GE1_107_Sep09_1_3.txt|
```

Comment: thank, this one works too. but it keeps the default font type (arial, i guess) and my thesis source file is using something else. so I'm using \_, as suggested below.